# Function to source .vimrc and .gvimrc

Tags: vim

I generally use GVim, but most of my configuration is done via .vimrc (like keymappings) because I want them in vim *and* gvim. So when I edit my vimrc and then source it from gvim, I have to source my .gvimrc after that in order to get my colorscheme back (since it's gvim only). I tried to write a function to do this, and ran into the problems described in the comments below:

```
function ReloadConfigs()
    :source ~/.vimrc
    if has("gui_running")
        :source ~/.gvimrc
    endif
endfunction
command! Recfg call ReloadConfigs()
" error: function already exists, add ! to replace it

function! ReloadConfigs()
    :source ~/.vimrc
    if has("gui_running")
        :source ~/.gvimrc
    endif
endfunction
command! Recfg call ReloadConfigs()
" error: cannot replace function, it is in use
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Or, since my .gvimrc only has a few lines, should I just put its contents into an `if has("gui_running")` block?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've put your function somewhere in your .vimrc. This means that, while it's being executed, the `:source .vimrc` is trying to redefine it, which is a problem. You could try doing this:

```
if !exists("*ReloadConfigs")
  function ReloadConfigs()
      :source ~/.vimrc
      if has("gui_running")
          :source ~/.gvimrc
      endif
  endfunction
  command! Recfg call ReloadConfigs()
endif
```

If the function is already defined, this should skip redefining it, avoiding the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that whatever you have in your .vimrc that's messing up gvim settings should be surrounded by an `if !has("gui_running")` block.

An autocmd seems to be the easiest way of handling what you're trying to do:

```
autocmd BufWritePre .gvimrc,.vimrc source <amatch>
```

This way you get your configuration file automatically reloaded when you save it without having to mess around with functions.  Alternatively, you could use a mapping to trigger `:source $MYVIMRC` or `:source $MYGVIMRC`.

Comment: There isn't anything in my .vimrc that "messes up" gvim. I simply use different colorschemes in vim and gvim. The gvim colorscheme is specified in .gvimrc. I also have the font, lines/cols, guioptions, and showtabline settings.

It seems like the `autocmd` line will only source the file that is written. So if I'm editing .vimrc in gvim and I write it, I will still have to source the gvimrc.

Comment: Why do you need to source the gvimrc though?  (Note my first sentence.)

Comment: I noted your first sentence. Vim and gvim use different colorschemes, as I said in the original post.

Comment: So why can't your .vimrc surround the colorscheme change (and so on) with `if !has("gui_running")`?

Comment: Yes, that is why I am proposing a different solution, one that works, than the one that you have in your OP, which does not work. Don't conditionally source a file, conditionally do the things that otherwise require sourcing the other file. Jeez.

Comment: I meant I mentioned using a `if has("gui_running")` block. Check the last sentence.

Comment: You say you put `if has...` around the `source $MYGVIMRC` line. I say put `if !has...` around the colorscheme and other changes in $MYVIMRC so that you don't have to source $MYGVIMRC. You do not see a difference?

Comment: Read the last line: 'Or, since my .gvimrc only has a few lines, should I just put its contents into an if has("gui_running") block?'

That would include the colorscheme.

Comment: You type 'g' where I do not. It is clear you're not reading what I've written.  This solution would work for you if you bother to follow what it suggests, without making any changes to .gvimrc or conditionally loading it.

Comment: I meant put the contents of `.gvimrc` inside an `if has("gui_running")` in `.vimrc`. I thought it was implied, but in retrospect I can see how it was ambiguous.

Comment: That was not ambiguous and is in fact the exact opposite solution from what I am proposing. Alas.